# Are my ID and phone number being used without my consent?

Tags: identity-theft

So here is the issue. Since the beginning of january, I started noticing something odd with my phone. Basically, I usually pay credits to be able to call people. The problem is this : after a few days or so, call credits get spent. Normally these payments last for a month or more because I don't really call people that much. Plus, it happened twice, I just paid last week and now it's gone again. Is someone using my Id and phone number to call. I'm kinda scared honestly, please help.

Comment: Have you asked the phone company? Checked the call log? Do credits have expiration conditions? Really hard for us to know any of that.

Comment: Are you sure you're hanging up? Are you sure you aren't "pocket-dialing"? Are you sure you aren't  calling "pay me" numbers which bill for more than the basic phone minutes? Definitely check the log to see where the minutes are going.